# Django staff users manage their own users that they have created only

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In my Django app a user can register to the site and receive staff_user privileges from the admin. After that the staff user can create and manage some other users (normal users) using default django admin site. Now, I would like to let the staff user see and manage only the users he created from the admin site, I don't want him to see other users created by another staff user.

how can I do that? I imagine I need to modify admin.py right?

I am using django version 1.11

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You need to override few methods in your admin.py. The following things needs to be applied.

1. Update user model to add created_by field
2. Override save method in admin to set created_by field
3. Override get queryset method to filter user's list based on created_by.

   ```
   class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
       list_display = ("username",)
       model = Profile


       def get_queryset(self, request):
           qs = super().get_queryset(request)
           if request.user.is_superuser:
               return qs

           return Profile.objects.filter(created_by=request.user) or qs.none()



       def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
           if change:
               obj.modified_by = request.user
           else:
               obj.created_by = request.user

           obj.save()
   ```

Comment: Can you please properly indent the code? I cant understand it